# Rendering newline character as a string in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I've looked into this quite a bit and all I'm seeing are solutions on how to show the newline character as a new line.

**I want to show the `"\n"` as a string in an Angular view.** It seems that Angular ignores it by default.

Example Text:

```
this.myText = "This is my \n example \n string: \n"
```

Example Output of `<div>{{ myText }}</div>`:

```
"This is my example string:"
```

Desired Output:

```
"This is my \n example \n string: \n"
```

Stackblitz: [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yngnir?file=src/app/app.component.html)

--

i.e. `style="white-space: pre-line"` or `<pre></pre>` or `[innerText]="myText"` is not what I want to do as I do not want to render the \n as a new line.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make it `{{ myText.split('\n').join('\\n') }}`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ujcazi?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution that seems more of an "Angular way" to do it would be to create a pipe for it:

`.ts`:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

/*
 * Returns the newline character "\n" as a string
 *
 */
@Pipe({ name: 'newlineAsString' })
export class NewlineAsStringPipe implements PipeTransform {
  
  constructor() {}

  transform(text: string) {
    return text.split('\n').join('\\n');
  }
}
```

`.html`:

```
<div>{{ myText | newlineAsString }}</div>
```